# Sanitation issue in href and src tags

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the API of AngularJS in `$sce` section I have found that
"a[href] and img[src] automatically sanitize their URLs and do not pass them through $sce.getTrusted"
however `$compileProvider` provides

- aHrefSanitizationWhitelist for sanitation of href
- imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist for sanitation of img[src]

My question is why do I need those methods if a[href] and img[src] automatically sanitize their URLs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you might have things you don't want sanitized. Typically in something like a newspaper site you might have some photo gallery that you control, plus a comment section. In the comments you wouldn't want people putting in naughty images or injecting XSS attacks there, but you do want yourself to have full control over the rest of the page. The whitelist allows you to differentiate between the two.

It's not necessary to touch these settings unless something you're trying to do actually breaks.

Comment: maybe I don't understand, but I think that aHrefSanitizationWhitelist  sanitizes the content of ng-href directive, and imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist sanitizes the content for <img ng-src directive. Is those methods sanitizes something else? since from your answer I understand that it sanitizes the content of the page and not the url itself. If it sanitizes the content via what directive/service/variable will be the "output" to the web page?

Comment: No, each of those is a regex. If the regex matches, the URL is _not_ sanitized. Typically you set that to match mydomain.com. Images pulled from http://example.com/some/path/file.jpg would be allowed, while images from http://example.org/path/to/naughty.jpg would be sanitized. This is a very common use-case for things like commenting systems, but if you don't need it you can certainly ignore it.